# Shuffling a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, shuffle

I have a function that takes a doubly linked list. Head is the first node and tail is the last node. There are 52 nodes (Deck of cards) what I'm trying to do is perform a a shuffle as if you shuffled them by hand. So you cut the deck in half take the bottom card off the first half place it in the new pile, take the bottom card off the other half and place it on top of that one.

So. Left Half is 1 2 3 Right Half is 4 5 6 After the shuffle 4 1 5 2 6 3

I know my mistake is in the pointers and that they are over-writing each other. I just don't know how to correctly sort through these lists and pluck them out one by one and stick them back together.

```
bool Shuffle(deck* &head, deck* &tail, int ShuffleAmnt)
```

{

```
deck* temp_tail = nullptr;
deck* temp_head = head;
deck* temp_list = new deck;
for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
    temp_head = temp_head->next;

temp_tail = temp_head->next;

temp_tail->previous = nullptr;

temp_head->next = nullptr;


while (head->next != NULL) // get to the bottom of head
    head = head->next;

temp_head->previous = nullptr;
temp_tail->next = nullptr;

for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
{
    temp_list->next = temp_head;
    temp_head = head->previous;
    temp_list = temp_list->next;
    temp_list->next = temp_tail;
}

head = temp_list;



return(true);
```

}

Comment: what does your third argument do?

Comment: Whose idea was it to represent a card deck with a linked list?  A `std::vector`, `std::array`, or just a plain old array makes more sense.

Comment: The safest way to shuffle a linked list is copy the data to an array, shuffle the array, and then copy the results of the array back to your list.  This is assuming you have functions that goes through your list, and functions to copy data back to your list.  Also, shuffling is supposed to be randomized, not "controlled" as your code seems to suggest.  Ex: the first card on the deck can go potentially anywhere in the deck after shuffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may not directly answer the question but it is here to guide and educate if that is desired.

The c++ standard library already has template implementations of (almost) ***every container type and logical operation you will ever need***. These building blocks are in use daily in billions of computers, have been optimised for efficiency with your compiler and have been peer-reviewed by every single one of the World's most expert programmers. In short, there is no reason to consider writing a linked list (`std::list`) or writing a shuffle algorithm (`std::random_shuffle`).

If you really do want to keep cards in a linked list (you don't, a vector is more natural) you can refactor to this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct Card {};

typedef std::list<Card> deck; // that's it - a complete linked list implementation

void shuffle_deck(deck& the_deck) {
    // c++11 takes advantage of efficiently copying by value.
    std::vector<Card> temp(std::make_move_iterator(the_deck.begin()),
                           std::make_move_iterator(the_deck.end()));

    // clear out the zombie objects that will have been left by the move
    the_deck.clear();

    // those clever fellows in the standards committee thought of everything...
    // even shuffling a deck of cards!
    std::random_shuffle(temp.begin(), temp.end());

    // move the cards back into the linked list in the correct order
    std::move(temp.begin(), temp.end(), back_inserter(the_deck));
}
```

If you decide to do the Right Thing(tm) and make your deck of cards a vector, it's even simpler:

```
typedef std::vector<Card> deck_of_cards;

void shuffle_deck(deck_of_cards& deck)
{
    std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
}
```

If you are looking forward to a rewarding career writing c++, take time to learn the standard library thoroughly - many c++ programmers don't bother to learn the `algorithm` library - this is a mistake. It is the foundation of elegant, maintainable code.

Here is a link to the documentation on `std::random_shuffle`. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

You will note that it is marked for removal from the standard as of c++17 as it is being superseded by the superior `std::shuffle`. However, for the purposes of this discussion I felt that this might serve as a distraction from the main point - which is to encourage you to learn and use the standard library :-)

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated and is proposed to be removed in 2017. Use `std::shuffle` instead.

Comment: completely agree. One of the difficulties of answering this kind of question is "how many steps forward do I take the OP"? Involving `std::shuffle` then introduces the concept of the generator which I felt was tangential to the problem being discussed.

Comment: I would say [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is documented well enough to be used by everyone who can read, but I get your point and find it legit too. You could think about adding a remark that `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in your answer though. I feel like this is worth to be mentioned.

Comment: Why is a LinkedList bad for a deck. In a deck you can only access the top or bottom card (head or tail) and you may constantly insert or remove cards from the top or bottom which LinkedList is supreme at doing. It seems like the perfect data structure for this.

Comment: @Hatefiend shuffling a linked list can be expensive because the random access time is linear.

Comment: @RichardHodges I guess it depends on how much you are shuffling a deck vs. how much you are inserting / adding right? Keep in mind `push_front` in `vector` is `O(n)` each time you use it because you have to shift

Comment: @Hatefiend while you might think that, in practice you'll find that the vector is quicker, because it suffers no pointer indirection or node allocation costs. It also has perfect cache locality, which is even more important. However, the theoretically perfect data structure for this is a std::deque. In practice though, unless the cards themselves are huge, it's no improvement over a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
bool Shuffle(deck* &head, deck* &tail, int ShuffleAmnt = 1)
{
  deck* temp_tail = nullptr;
  deck* temp_head = head;
  for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
    temp_head = temp_head->next;

  temp_tail = temp_head->next;
  temp_tail->previous = nullptr;

  temp_head->next = nullptr;
  temp_head = head;

  temp_head_next = temp_head->next;
  temp_head_next->previous = temp_head;

  temp_tail_next->next = temp_tail->next;
  temp_tail_next->previous = temp_tail;

  head = temp_tail;

  for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
 {
    temp_tail->next = temp_head; 
    temp_head->previous = temp_tail;
    temp_head->next = temp_tail->next;

    temp_tail = temp_head_next;
    temp_head = temp_head_next;

    temp_head_next = temp_head->next;
    temp_head_next->previous = temp_head;

    temp_tail_next->next = temp_tail->next;
    temp_tail_next->previous = temp_tail;
  }
tail = temp_head;
return(true);
```

}